# How to use lodash as helper for the following code

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, lodash, immutable.js

I use the following code which is working  and I wonder if there is a way to make it simple using lodash or other lib?
I'm getting array with value and add it line by line and this is just the beginning :) so I wonder if there is a better way in JS

```
_add: function(url, oConfig, CacheParameters, aDest,
    bParameters, aReus) {
    for (var i = 0; CacheParameters && i < CacheParameters.length; i++) {
        url.addSearch(CacheParameters[i].name, CacheParameters[i].value);
    }
    for (i = 0; aDest && i < aDest.length; i++) {
        url.addSearch(aDest[i].name, aDest[i].value);
    }
    for (i = 0; bParameters && i < bParameters.length; i++) {
        url.addSearch(bParameters[i].name, bParameters[i].value);
    }
    for (i = 0; aReus && i < aReus.length; i++) {
        url.addSearch(aReus[i].name, aReus[i].value);
    }
    for (i = 0; oConfig.bParameters && i < oConfig.bParameters.length; i++) {
        var oParam = oConfig.bParameters[i];
        url.addSearch(oParam.paramName, oParam.paramValue);
    }
    return url;
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tested this, but something along the lines of this should work. You do not need lodash for this approach. Basically what you are doing is to iterate through an array and pass two of its properties to `url.addSearch`. Hence we can write a function that accepts an array and two fields:

```
_add: function(url, oConfig, CacheParameters, aDest, bParameters, aReus) {
  function addSearchToUrl(arr, field1, field2) {
    arr.forEach(function (item) {
      url.addSearch(item[field1], item[field2]);
    });
  }

  addSearchToUrl(CacheParameters, 'name', 'value');
  addSearchToUrl(aDest, 'name', 'value');
  addSearchToUrl(bParameters, 'name', 'value');
  addSearchToUrl(aReus, 'name', 'value');
  addSearchToUrl(oConfig.bParameters, 'paramName', 'paramValue');
}
```